# Can GWT 2.4.0 run with Java EE5?

Tags: java, gwt, compatibility, java-ee-5

We use WebSphere 7.x  (It supports Java ee 5). We want to use gwt 2.4.0 and it's feature - gwt RPC.
 GWT RPC mechanism causes to use servlet in server side (which works only by extending RemoteServiceServlet - gwt class).  Does GWT (specifically RemoteServiceServlet) will work with Java ee 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT compiles down to the html/css/javascript and it is possible make RPC calls to any platform (java, php, python, etc.).

`RemoteServiceServlet` works on server side. As long as you deploy your war to the container that supports `servlet-api` it will work fine.